# forEach into for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I have the following games object:

```
window.games ={
    "game1": {
        name: "game1", 
        url: "", 
    },
    "game2": {
        name: "game2", 
        url: "", 
    },
    "game3": {
        name: "game3", 
        url: "", 
    },
    "game4": {
        name: "game4", 
        url: "", 
    },
};
```

and the following selected games array

```
window.selectedGames = ["game2", "game3"];
```

I am using a forEach to take each game from the selected games array and using the data from the object to render an html element:

```
 selectedGames.forEach(game => {
        for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(games)) {
            if (key === game) {
                var jackpotContainer = document.querySelector(".sub-jackpot-container");
                gameContainer = document.createElement('div');
                jackpotContainer.appendChild(gameContainer);
                gameBox = document.createElement('div');
                link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = value.url;
                gameContainer.appendChild(gameBox);
                gameContainer.appendChild(link);
                gameName = document.createElement('span');
                gameName.classList = 'game-name';
                gameName.innerHTML = value.name;
            }
        }
    });
```

I cannot figure out how can I change this forEach into a for loop so this can be supported on IE as well. I'll be very thankful for any help.

Comment: You want to change only `forEach` or inner `for..of` loop also to simple `for` loop?

Comment: [IE doesn't support object/array destructuring either.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @palaѕн well, generally adjust this so it would run in IE as well...

Comment: Ok, you have got lots of solutions already. Let me know if you are still facing any issues regarding this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
selectedGames.forEach(game => {
    // ...
});
```

would become:

```
for (var i=0; i < selectedGames.length; i++) {
    var game = selectedGames[i];
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to refactor all of your code to support IE, you can use a transpiler such as Babel to convert all of your code. For your example input, babel will output something like

```
"use strict";

function _slicedToArray(arr, i) { return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _unsupportedIterableToArray(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest(); }

function _nonIterableRest() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."); }

function _unsupportedIterableToArray(o, minLen) { if (!o) return; if (typeof o === "string") return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); var n = Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8, -1); if (n === "Object" && o.constructor) n = o.constructor.name; if (n === "Map" || n === "Set") return Array.from(o); if (n === "Arguments" || /^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n)) return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); }

function _arrayLikeToArray(arr, len) { if (len == null || len > arr.length) len = arr.length; for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(len); i < len; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; }

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) { if (typeof Symbol === "undefined" || !(Symbol.iterator in Object(arr))) return; var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; }

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr; }

selectedGames.forEach(function (game) {
  for (var _i = 0, _Object$entries = Object.entries(games); _i < _Object$entries.length; _i++) {
    var _Object$entries$_i = _slicedToArray(_Object$entries[_i], 2),
        key = _Object$entries$_i[0],
        value = _Object$entries$_i[1];

    if (key === game) {
      var jackpotContainer = document.querySelector(".sub-jackpot-container");
      gameContainer = document.createElement('div');
      jackpotContainer.appendChild(gameContainer);
      gameBox = document.createElement('div');
      link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = value.url;
      gameContainer.appendChild(gameBox);
      gameContainer.appendChild(link);
      gameName = document.createElement('span');
      gameName.classList = 'game-name';
      gameName.innerHTML = value.name;
    }
  }
});
```

See it [here](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQZwpgNmDGAuYBMDiBDAtmEA6AZgewCcBRFaACwAoBzdMYAXgD5gBvAKGE68_wOAoBuKPgG0A1mACeAGmBCIAVzABdYHhzAA8gCMAVjFhYwAO1gEAlpmq0QASlusO3Z53MaKEyQ3r1gNDA7sLsFcQny6pGIADniwAMJ4pijmxmB8vgh40AoYplgAjkoEkgDKkAaEFABEWCAK2gC0EdDRsQ3QibDJqQRVtgDcTiEu_mAJSSlpDMCZ2bmG0ARgKPBEUPMUAOQI5gKbA0PD3M2t8Z3daVgoUVEmCHFk5hAI1hjjXZMEB0cjtABCeAAHtNZjkTAsliswGswBttrt9oMfs4ICkxCCsmC8otlqt1uCtihEYdkajjGIsGQlhpfPIlFgFAQIEjkVxRu8LgQrjc7g8ni9RgDAd9WZx2edPtzbsZ7o9nhQyWIRaLRgA5WgYubgrA4qEwuEgKIoYzE0Vi2jqjA6iAoEAgAAy5hAsGmm1GDWMtE2LJVFtoWBSPQAEgAVACy9umdLAWE9GB9wwAviSuMnuImBkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.6&externalPlugins=). Look up how to include it in your build process as you should not be actually putting code in the online editor. This is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your loop I think its better to loop through the elements you want rather than looping through everything and checking if it matches or not.

Something like this:

```js
window.games ={
    "game1": {
        name: "game1", 
        url: "", 
    },
    "game2": {
        name: "game2", 
        url: "", 
    },
    "game3": {
        name: "game3", 
        url: "", 
    },
    "game4": {
        name: "game4", 
        url: "", 
    },
};

window.selectedGames = ["game2", "game3"];

window.selectedGames.forEach(selected_game => {
  game = window.games[selected_game];
  
  if (game !== undefined) {
    // You can do whatever you want here
    console.log(game.name);
    console.log(game.url);
  }
  
 });
```